# What does purge-local-repository actually purge?

Tags: maven, plugins, maven-dependency-plugin, purge

I am running the following command from within a maven project directory:

```
mvn dependency:purge-local-repository
```

What is the expected behavior?

Will it delete (and re-download?) all the dependencies already existing in my local repo for **that particular project** (i.e. whose directory I am in) or will it delete **all** the contents of my local repo?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

By default, [`purge-local-repository`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/purge-local-repository-mojo.html) will remove from the local repository all the files associated to the version of each dependency (including transitive) of the project it is ran on:

> Remove the project dependencies from the local repository, and optionally re-resolve them.

The several factors coming into play are:

- Transitive dependencies are purged by the plugin by default; this is configurable through the [`actTransitively`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/purge-local-repository-mojo.html#actTransitively) parameter.
- All of the purged artifacts from the local repository are re-resolved by default; this is configurable through the [`reResolve`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/purge-local-repository-mojo.html#reResolve) parameter.
- The actual files that are purged from the local repository correspond to all the files associated to the version of the purged artifact. For example, if the dependency `foo:bar:1.0` is purged, all the files under the path `foo/bar/1.0/*` will be removed. This is configurable through the [`resolutionFuzziness`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/purge-local-repository-mojo.html#resolutionFuzziness) parameter (whose default value is `version`):

  - A value of `artifactId` would purge all the files under the path to artifact id of the artifact being purged. In the example above, all files under `foo/bar/**` would be purged (so, all versions are removed).
  - A value of `groupId` would purge all the files under the path to group id of the artifact being purged. In the example above, all files under `foo/**` would be purged (so, all versions for all artifact ids are removed).
  - A value of `file` would only purge the file for the artifact being purged. In the example above, only the files `bar-1.0.jar*` will be removed (this includes any `sha1` they could have). It would not purge the associated POM file.

You can see which artifacts are going to be purged by printing the list of all dependencies for the project with the [`list`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/list-mojo.html) goal:

```
mvn dependency:list
```

optionally adding [`excludeTransitive`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/list-mojo.html#excludeTransitive) to this command, if you decide not to purge transitive dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Using same purge but in details,
 If project A and project B (Jar) build on local and Project A depends on B (which is in local Repo) can be resolved like

mvn dependency:purge-local-repository -Dinclude=com.xxxx.projectB:projectB

and add the dependency in Project A will resolve the issue.

```
<dependency>
                <groupId>com.xxxx.projectB</groupId>
                <artifactId>projectB</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
```

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 0):

Following

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/purge-local-repository-mojo.html

we that

```
dependency:purge-local-repository
```

removes the project dependencies from the local repository, and optionally re-resolve them.