# Problem with creating a Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, web

i am still a beginner with spring boot, and i have a bunch of questions. 
First of all, do i have to download maven in my pc and add it to my pc path envirement to make spring boot work correctly ? 
Secondly, Spring boot wasn't able to work, was doing a hello world app and there were lot of errors on the console one of them is "SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".. why that ? i looked for the error and followed some mvn command line steps "mvn dependency:purge-local-repository", and my app finally worked.. but do i have to run this command everytime i create a spring boot app ? isn't everything supposed to be alright since it's only a hello world app ? ..
Thank you

Comment: hello new guy ! Welcome on stack overflow ! I'm in charge of question moderation so I have to tell people what is wrong in the way they write their question
do not forget to write code, error messages etc, everything that is technical, in a "code field" (you select the part of the text that is code etc and you click on "code" on the formating bar)
good luck !

Comment: thanx, and i haven't wrote any code this is why i didn't post any... all i did was, build a project and click the run button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need to have installed maven or gradle  in order to run your application. And it needs to be reachable, so you have to configure your system variables accordingly.

You can find more details [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-running-your-application.html).

As per the maven error, maven keeps all the artifacts you need to run your application in a shared folder with all versions, sometimes maven could have corrupted files or a mismatch in version so you need to purge the repository and download artifacts again.

You can find a more detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40381906/what-does-purge-local-repository-actually-purge).

Even when you are coding a simple application, spring-boot bring up a lot of code for supporting operations you may require, such code is self configured and hidden.